# Google Voice plugin for gmail not working (12.04 x64 & firefox 17.0)

Tags: firefox, gmail, google, google-talk, google-chat

When I try to use the "call phones" feature from the gmail chat pane, I get the following message with a link to the download of the *.deb file.

> Please download the voice plugin to make a call.

It used to work, and I'm not sure when it stopped working because I don't use it frequently.

So far I've purged the `google-talkplugin` (via synaptic) and tried manually reinstalling the 64 bit .deb file, both through Software Center and with `dpkg -i *.deb`. No success yet.

I use a pretty standard set of code:

- ubuntu 12.04.01 x86_64 (3.2.0-33-generic)
- firefox (17.0)
- google-talkplugin (3.10.2.0-1)

**update:** I tried the 32bit .deb file. Did not work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer - solution - to your question.**

If the google-talkplugin is problematic , then is problematic and is not a fault of Ubuntu.

I will tell you what I did to make it work , but (again) this is not a solution. (maybe a workaround).

Download and install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/) , I don't know how ,but for a reason , the plugin works there.

When you have installed Google Chrome , then open Firefox and open a terminal too and run this command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure google-talkplugin
```

Probably it will work with Firefox too. (worked for me).

Comment: well, you may not call it a solution but it worked (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4bnsx5rgSc). I went with chromium-browser instead (as to have better control of the package). After getting google-talkplugin to work on both chromium and firefox, I purged chromium. The dpkg-reconfigure command wasn't necessary but I ran it anyway. Many thanks!